# .Net Core EntitiyFramework Top Row Of Joined Table

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get all students last attended class from database. I wrote tsql code and it works very well howevery i couldn't do the same on entityframework core.

This code below works for me.

```
select a.student, b.class, b.attend from students a inner join class b on b.id = (
select top 1 id
from class
where student = a.student order by attend desc
)
```

Also this is my attemp on writing EF query.

```
datavalue = db.students.join(
db.class, m => m.student,
s => s.student, (m, s) => new joinedstudentswclass { class = s.class, student = m.student }
).tolist();
```

Answer (score 0):

u should use firstOrDefault to get a single record.

if u wanna order something, you should be used orderBy methods.

```
.OrderBy(x => x.City) for ascending students
.OrderByDescending(x => x.City) for descending students
```

the code should be something like

```
 OrderByDescending(x=>x.Students).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It gave en error like "Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'iot.Models.Joinedstudentswclass' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<iot.Models.Joinedstudentswclass>'"

Comment: can you change variables to var?

Comment: Ok i change it to var instead. now "could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'"

Comment: What is ur ef / core version?

Comment: .net core 3.1 and ef 5.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Without navigation properties:

```cs
var query = 
   from s in db.students
   from c in db.Where(c => c.student == s.student).OrderByDescending(c => c.attend).Take(1)
   select new joinedstudentswclass 
   { 
      class = c, 
      student = s 
   };

var datavalue = query.ToList()
```

If you have navigation property `Classes` in `student` class:

```cs
var query = 
   from s in db.students
   from c in s.Classes.OrderByDescending(c => c.attend).Take(1)
   select new joinedstudentswclass 
   { 
      class = c, 
      student = s 
   };

var datavalue = query.ToList()
```